# Spark is not able the serialize the task, using UDF in filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
>   serializable  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1857)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)   at
>   org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint$$anonfun$2.apply(DateFormatConstraint.scala:32)
>     at
>   org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint$$anonfun$2.apply(DateFormatConstraint.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.exadatum.ddq.core.Runner$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Runner.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.exadatum.ddq.core.Runner$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Runner.scala:22)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>     at org.exadatum.ddq.core.Runner$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Runner.scala:22)
>     at org.exadatum.ddq.core.Runner$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Runner.scala:20)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>     at org.exadatum.ddq.core.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:20)   at
>   org.exadatum.ddq.core.RunCheck.(RunCheck.scala:104)     at
>   org.exadatum.ddq.core.DQJobTrigger$.main(DQJobTrigger.scala:39)   at
>   org.exadatum.ddq.core.DQJobTrigger.main(DQJobTrigger.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@1d9bd4d6)
>     - field (class: org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint, name: sc, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
>     - object (class org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint, DateFormatConstraint(startdate,java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f76f1a0,org.apache.spark.SparkContext@1d9bd4d6,xdqdemo.customer_details))
>     - field (class: org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint$$anonfun$2, name:
>   $outer, type: class org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint)
>     - object (class org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint$$anonfun$2,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint$$anonfun$2)
>     - object (class org.exadatum.ddq.constraints.DateFormatConstraint$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2, name:
>   func$2, type: interface scala.Function1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(startdate#2))
>     - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(UDF(startdate#2)))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryColumnarTableScan,
>   name: predicates, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryColumnarTableScan,
>   InMemoryColumnarTableScan [phone_number#0,name#1,startdate#2],
>   [UDF(startdate#2)], InMemoryRelation
>   [phone_number#0,name#1,startdate#2], true, 10000, StorageLevel(false,
>   true, false, true, 1), ConvertToUnsafe, None )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryColumnarTableScan$$anonfun$doExecute$1,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryColumnarTableScan)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryColumnarTableScan$$anonfun$doExecute$1,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1, name: f$22,
>   type: interface scala.Function1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, name: f, type: interface scala.Function3)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[8] at rdd at DateFormatConstraint.scala:32)
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: *rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@316975be)
>     - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@316975be))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies*, type: interface
>   scala.collection.Seq)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[9] at rdd at DateFormatConstraint.scala:32)
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: *rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@526fbb80)
>     - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@526fbb80))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies*, type: interface
>   scala.collection.Seq)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[10] at rdd at DateFormatConstraint.scala:32)
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1, name: $outer, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1, )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12, name: $outer,
>   type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12, )
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
>     ... 39 more

CODE SNIPPET :

```
val fun = (df: DataFrame) => {

format.setLenient(false)
val cannotBeDate = udf((column: String) => column != null && Try(format.parse(column)).isFailure)
val maybeCannotBeDateCount = Try(df.filter(cannotBeDate(new Column(columnName))).count);

/** Utility to persist all of the bad records   **/

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import hiveContext.implicits._

//Writing all Bad records
//val intermediateYriteToHiveDf = df.filter(cannotBeDate(new Column(columnName)))
val writeToHiveDf = df.filter(cannotBeDate(new Column(columnName)))

var recordLists = new ListBuffer[List[(String, String, String)]]()
writeToHiveDf.rdd.collect().foreach {
  row =>
    val item = row.mkString("-")
    val recordList: List[(String, String, String)] = List(List(tableName, "ALWAYS_NULL_CONSTRAINT", item))
      .map { case List(a, b, c) => (a, b, c) }
    recordLists += recordList
}
val listRDD = sc.parallelize(recordLists.flatten)
val dataFrameToHive: DataFrame = listRDD.toDF("table_name", "constraint_applied", "data")
dataFrameToHive.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("xdqdemo.bad_records")



DateFormatConstraintResult(
  this,
  data = maybeCannotBeDateCount.toOption.map(DateFormatConstraintResultData),
  status = ConstraintUtil.tryToStatus[Long](maybeCannotBeDateCount, _ == 0)
)
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `format.parse` that is causing the problem. You haven't included the initialisation of this `format`-variable in the snippet, but either the `format`-class is not serializable in itself or the class from which you are initializing `format` is not serializable (most likely the latter)

Comment: format is an argument which is initialized as format = SimpleDateFormat("some-date-format");

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Otherwise, please include a little more of the code. In particular, in what object/class is this `fun`-function declared and where is the `format` variable instantiated? And does the classes include any class variables or other inner classes?

Comment: And sample input data should help as well.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my code, sorry I am new so was not able to format it well

Comment: And I was able to solve my problem with the help of my colleagues at Exadatum.

Spark was not able to serialize the udf as it contains the unserializable class which here was `format` which is of the type SimpleDateFormat and though I can not explain properly about serialization in spark as the same issue came up in my another code where constraint check was aSetVariable.contains("toBeChecked") so according to this Sets should not be serializable by spark, but if we pack all the operations inside a singleton object which extends Serializable class it works. Next comment I have code  snippet

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I have added solution at the end of my question, I was not able to put code snippet in comment, I will take me while to learn about stackOverflow

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Solution at the end of the question, excuse me for poor editing I need to get a hang on stackOverflow

Comment: you can answer the question down below not in the question itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 object checkConstraint extends Serializable{
  def checkDateFormat(format: SimpleDateFormat,df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    format.setLenient(false)
    val checkDateFormat = (column: String) => Try(format.parse(column)).isFailure
    val cannotBeDate = udf((column: String) => column != null && checkDateFormat(column))
    df.filter(cannotBeDate(new Column(columnName)))
  }
}


val writeToHiveDf = checkConstraint.checkDateFormat(format,df)
```

hence all the computations are packed inside a singleton object, which returns a required dataframe